# Java code for checking if variables x and y are between 0 and 1?

Tags: java

I don't know how to write code in Java to check if x and y are both strictly between 0 and 1.

I have tried a lot of code, but it doesn't work. Can I get some help?

Comment: C'mon....post the code you've tried.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: We can't debug code we can't see. Post it please with details about what exactly does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Without much to go on:

```
double x = getX();
double y = getY();

if ( x > 0 && x < 1 && y > 0 && y < 1 ) {
    // TODO
}
```

Edit: Removed equality validity since the question mentioned "strictly".

Answer (score 2):

```
double y = 0.1,x = 0.2;    

if ( ( x < 1 && x > 0) && ( y < 1 && y > 0 ) ) 
{
    // than do whatever 
}
```

That should work if you do not include 1 and 0 as valid values

Comment: Can Java have a capitalized `if`?

Comment: No. that won't compile, its also formatted poorly

Comment: It for captilized automatically as I am in my phone, check out the edit I made , it should now work

Comment: your code is still poorly formatted

Comment: did it from the computer now... much better.